# Edit (recode, collapse, order) factor levels with regex matching

Tags: r, regex, r-factor

I find manipulating factor variables in R unduly complicated. Things I frequently want to do when cleaning factors include:

- Resorting levels – not just to set a reference category, but also put all levels in a logical (non-alphabetical order) for summary tables. `x <- factor(x, levels = new.order)`
- Recode / rename factor levels – to simplify names and/or collapse multiple categories into one group. For one-to-one recoding `levels(x) <-  new.levels(x)` or `plyr::revalue`, see [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/) or [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Recoding_data/) for examples. `car::recode` can perform several one-to-many matches in a single statement, but doesn't support regex matching.
- Drop levels – not just drop unused levels, but set some levels to missing. (Eg. those with error codes).
  `x <- factor(as.character(x), exclude = drop.levels)`
- Add levels – to show categories with zero counts.

What would be great is to have a single function that can do all of the above at once, allows fuzzy (regex) matching for recoding and dropping factors, can be used within other functions (eg. `lapply` or `dplyr::mutate`), and has a simple (consistent) syntax.

I’ve posted my best attempt at this as an answer below, but please let me know if I've missed a function that already exists or if the code can be improved.

EDIT

I've been made aware of the `forcats` package, which is subtitled *Tools for working with Categorical Variables (Factors)*. The package has many options for resorting levels ('fct_infreq', 'fct_reorder', 'fct_relevel', ...), recoding/grouping levels ('fct_recode', 'fct_lump', 'fct_collapse'), dropping levels ('fct_recode'), and adding levels ('fct_expand'). But there are no plans for it to support regex matching (https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/issues/214).

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a single step'?

Comment: @effel I guess I was thinking of having a one-line command to do everything that could be incorporated in a lapply command or similar. Although I acknowledge this can be accomplished in R by packaging everything into a custom function. I also wondered if I had missed a command from dplyr or other package that does what `car::recode` does but with a friendlier syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: A few years later I've added the `xfactor` function on github to accomplish the above. It is still a work in progress so please let me know if there are any bugs etc.

```
devtools::install_github("jwilliman/xfactor")
```

```r
library(xfactor)

# Create example factor
x <- xfactor(c("dogfish", "rabbit","catfish", "mouse", "dirt"))
levels(x)
#> [1] "catfish" "dirt"    "dogfish" "mouse"   "rabbit"

# Factor levels can be reordered by passing an unnamed vector to the levels
# statement. Levels not included in the replace statement get moved to the end
# or dropped if exclude = TRUE.
xfactor(x, levels = c("mouse", "rabbit"))
#> [1] dogfish rabbit  catfish mouse   dirt   
#> Levels: mouse rabbit catfish dirt dogfish

xfactor(x, levels = c("mouse", "rabbit"), exclude = TRUE)
#> [1] <NA>   rabbit <NA>   mouse  <NA>  
#> Levels: mouse rabbit

# Factor levels can be recoded, collapse, and ordered by passing a named
# vector to the levels statement. Where the vector names are the new factor
# levels and the vector values are regex expressions for the old levels.
# Duplicated new levels will be collapsed.

xfactor(x, levels = c("Sea" = "fish", "Land" = "rab|mou"))
#> [1] Sea  Land Sea  Land dirt
#> Levels: Sea Land dirt

# Factor levels can be dropped by passing a regex expression (or vector) to
# the exclude statement

xfactor(x, exclude = "fish")
#> [1] <NA>   rabbit <NA>   mouse  dirt  
#> Levels: dirt mouse rabbit

# The function will work within other functions

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- data.frame(n = 1:5, x)
df %>%
  mutate(y = xfactor(x, levels = c("Sea" = "fish", "Land" = "rab|mou", "Air"), exclude = "di"))
#>   n       x    y
#> 1 1 dogfish  Sea
#> 2 2  rabbit Land
#> 3 3 catfish  Sea
#> 4 4   mouse Land
#> 5 5    dirt <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>