# Collapsing multiple factor levels of (messy) character variable in R

Tags: r, character, factors, levels

I struggle to collapse multiple factor levels into only three factor levels of one specific variable in R Studio.

My point of departure is a `data.table` with 250 variables and roughly 4,000 rows. For one factor variable I want to collpase it's 75 levels into 3 levels. Moreover, of the 75 levels, 4 levels should be ignored (or set to NA before) since they include controversial information. This factor variable is based on survey answers that also include individual answers in text format. Sometimes even the language differs. So, it's a bit messy.

I tried to collapse these 75 levels (or 71 levels if respective observations set to NA before) into 3 in two different ways. However, R always returns a `+` instead of a `>` in the console and I can't continue to perform any other commands. Of course I can stop this by hitting `Esc` but this does not help me receiving my desired result.

So, this imaginary example should show what I tried:

1) using the `levels` and `list` functions

```
levels(dt$x) <- list("No"=c("I don't allow anything", "..."), 
"Yes"= c("Number of visitors ,annual sales, sales growth, number of customers", "Net sales", "..."), 
"Maybe"=c("The CEO's approval is needed.", "To be discussed"))
```

2) using the `forcats` package

```
dt$x %>%
fct_collapse(No= c("I don't allow anything", "..."), 
Yes= c("Number of visitors ,annual sales, sales growth", "number of customers", "Net sales", "..."), 
Maybe=c("The CEO's approval is needed.", "To be discussed"))
```

I assume the problem arises due to how the original variable is structured. Does anyone have an idea how I could address that?

A big thank you upfront!

Best,
Ilka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine actually provided the answer. It's nothing to do with the data structure.

This does the job:

```
dt$x <- fct_collapse(dt$x, 
                          No = c(
                            "I don't allow anything", 
                             "..."),
                          Yes= c(
                             "Number of visitors ,annual sales, sales growth",
                             "number of customers", 
                             "Net sales", 
                             "..."),
                          Maybe= c(
                              "The CEO's approval is needed.", 
                              "To be discussed")
                               )
```

I still don't know why the first option I posted above doesn't work though (it did perfectly well with another variable).

Comment: Note that, if you want to exclude some levels, you need to set these observations to NA before making the variable a factor (or make it a character, set observations to NA and then make it a factor again). When doing this while the variable is a factor, these levels will still be there in the new variable but with 0 observations.

Answer (score 0):

dt$x surely is a "factor". To assign different values to a factor column, you should first convert data to "character" type

```
class(dt$x) # should be factor
dt$x <- as.character(dt$x)
class(dt$x) # should be "character"  

# a list of collapsed Categories
toCollapseCategories <- list(
    "No"=c("I don't allow anything", "..."), 
    "Yes"= c("Number of visitors ,annual sales, sales growth, number of customers", "Net 
           sales", "..."), 
    "Maybe"=c("The CEO's approval is needed.", "To be discussed")
)

dt$x[dt$x %in% toCollapseCategories$No] <- "No"
dt$x[dt$x %in% toCollapseCategories$Yes] <- "Yes"
dt$x[dt$x %in% toCollapseCategories$Maybe] <- "Maybe"

# and then get a factor
dt$x <- as.factor(dt$x)
class(dt$x) # factor
```

Of course, code can be optimized but dt$x should be a character in order to replace elements

Comment: Thanks for that idea, Marcelo. I tried it and first it seemed to work well, but somehow I end up with 7 levels instead of 3. I guess one of them is the NAs and maybe the other levels got somehow doubled? Anyways, as I've just posted, a friend actually showed me a way how to overcome my challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function `xfactor` on github to help with exactly this kind of situation. It allows for recoding of factor levels with regex matching, so can be useful for working with messy data. It also allows you to drop factor levels with regex matching using the 'exclude' statement.

```
devtools::install_github("jwilliman/xfactor")
library(xfactor)

dt$x <- xfactor::xfactor(dt$x, levels = c(
  No = "don't|never",
  Yes = "sales|visitors|customers",
  Maybe = "approval|discuss"),
  exclude = "irrelevant", ignore.case = TRUE)
  )
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800944/4241780 for further examples.

By the way, if R is returning a `+` instead of a `>` in the console, you have probably missed a closing `)` or `"` somewhere!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer JWilliman. I tried it just to see whether it works (I already got a running solution which I posted above). 1) There is a bracket missing at the end of your code. Still I get the following error when trying your package 'operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types'

Comment: I first made the mistake to write No="don't"|"never", etc. So the ones who want to use this solution should note that it has to be No="don't|never", etc. However, I think your code, JWilliman, does not work with very similar input. I get the error 'Warning message: Multiple matches for:' In my data all possible answers are listed after one another within the variable and 2 or more observations might have 10 similar entries and differ only by 1 entry.

Comment: @Ilka Thank you for trying it. The error message is to warn you that a single entry is matched by multiple different levels (eg. "I don't have customers" would be matched with 'No' and 'Yes'  in the example above). You would need to alter you regex expressions to prevent multiple matches - but yes it sounds like your data might be best suited to absolutely matches as with `fct_collapse` rather than fuzzy matches using regex expressions.