# Is there a faster way to recode character data when it's actually a factor?

Tags: r, string, performance, vector, recode

I often deal with character data that need some recoding. One common scenario is that a character vector that's being recorded is a factor *in essence*, but not necessarily in *class*. Consider for example, a `chr` vector such as the following `vec`:

```r
set.seed(2021)
vec <- sample(rep(c("animal_dog_xyz", "animal_cat_abc", "animal_alligator_tyl"), 10))
vec
#>  [1] "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_alligator_tyl" "animal_cat_abc"      
#>  [4] "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_alligator_tyl" "animal_alligator_tyl"
#>  [7] "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_cat_abc"      
#> [10] "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_cat_abc"      
#> [13] "animal_alligator_tyl" "animal_alligator_tyl" "animal_alligator_tyl"
#> [16] "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_alligator_tyl"
#> [19] "animal_alligator_tyl" "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_dog_xyz"      
#> [22] "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_cat_abc"       "animal_dog_xyz"      
#> [25] "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_dog_xyz"      
#> [28] "animal_dog_xyz"       "animal_alligator_tyl" "animal_alligator_tyl"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

If I want to recode this vector and extract only the animal name, I would go with a solution that is suited for character data:

```r
library(stringr)

sapply(str_split(vec, "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2)
#>  [1] "dog"       "alligator" "cat"       "cat"       "alligator" "alligator"
#>  [7] "cat"       "cat"       "cat"       "dog"       "dog"       "cat"      
#> [13] "alligator" "alligator" "alligator" "cat"       "dog"       "alligator"
#> [19] "alligator" "cat"       "dog"       "cat"       "cat"       "dog"      
#> [25] "dog"       "dog"       "dog"       "dog"       "alligator" "alligator"
```

### The Problem

If the vector is very long, such recoding procedure takes a long time. R would iterate over each vector element and apply the procedure. This seems inefficient given that there are only 3 unique values in the vector. In other words, we don't need to go one-by-one over the elements and figure out what should be the recoded value.

Here, `vec_long` is of length 30000. This is how much it would take to recode it on my machine.

```r
vec_long <- sample(rep(c("animal_dog_xyz", "animal_cat_abc", "animal_alligator_tyl"), 10000))
length(vec_long)
#> [1] 30000

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(sapply(str_split(vec_long, "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                             expr     min       lq     mean
#>  sapply(str_split(vec_long, "_", n = 3), `[`, 2) 51.6972 52.66918 57.42299
#>    median      uq     max neval
#>  54.47867 58.7653 115.754   100
```

Is there a way to leverage the fact that this vector is actually a `factor`? Thus to identify the unique values ("levels"), recode them, and re-deploy to the entire vector length? Is there such a procedure that will speed up processing time?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

---

I just want to summarize my testing based on @GKi's answer, @ThomasIsCoding's answer, and @user20650's comment.

```r
## The Data
set.seed(2021)

unique_vals <- c("animal_dog_xyz", "animal_cat_abc", "animal_alligator_tyl")

vec <- sample(rep(unique_vals, 10))
vec_long <- sample(rep(unique_vals, 1000))
vec_very_long <- sample(unique_vals, 100000))
```

```r
## The functions

## function #1 -- as @user20650 proposed
via_fac_levels <- function(x) {
  x_factor <- factor(x)
  levels(x_factor) <- sapply(str_split(levels(x_factor), "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2)
  as.character(x_factor)
}
####################

## function #2 --  as @GKi proposed
via_fac_no_levels <- function(x) {
  x_factor <- as.factor(x)
  x_factor <- sapply(strsplit(levels(x_factor), "_", TRUE), `[`, 2)[x_factor]
  as.character(x_factor)
}
####################

## function #3 -- the original slow method shown in the question
via_chr_only <- function(x) {
  sapply(str_split(x, "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2)
}

####################

## function #4 -- as @ThomasIsCoding proposed
via_read_table <- function(x) {
  read.table(text = paste0(x, collapse = "\n"), sep = "_", header = FALSE)$V2
}

###################

## function #5 -- forcats::fct_relabel()
via_fct_relabel <- function(x) {
  x_factor <- as.factor(x)
  x_factor <- fct_relabel(x_factor, ~sapply(str_split(.x, "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2))
  as.character(x_factor)
}
```

```r
## Performance assessment
### I ran it on Rstudio cloud
bm_short <- bench::mark(fac_levels = via_fac_levels(vec),
                  fac_no_levels = via_fac_no_levels(vec),
                  chr = via_chr_only(vec), 
                  read_t = via_read_table(vec),
                  fct_relabel = via_fct_relabel(vec),
                  iterations = 1000)

bm_long <- bench::mark(fac_levels = via_fac_levels(vec_long),
                        fac_no_levels = via_fac_no_levels(vec_long),
                        chr = via_chr_only(vec_long), 
                       read_t = via_read_table(vec_long),
                       fct_relabel = via_fct_relabel(vec_long),
                       iterations = 1000)

bm_very_long <- bench::mark(fac_levels = via_fac_levels(vec_very_long),
                  fac_no_levels = via_fac_no_levels(vec_very_long),
                  chr = via_chr_only(vec_very_long),
                  read_t = via_read_table(vec_very_long),
                  fct_relabel = via_fct_relabel(vec_very_long),
                  iterations = 1000)
```

```r
## visualize
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(beeswarm)

autoplot(bm_short) + ggtitle("data of length 30")
autoplot(bm_long) + ggtitle("data of length 3000")
autoplot(bm_very_long) + ggtitle("data of length 300000")
```

[image: bm_short]
[image: bm_long]
[image: bm_very_long]

```r
## verify all functions give the same output
v1 <- via_fac_levels(vec_long)
v2 <- via_fac_no_levels(vec_long)
v3 <- via_chr_only(vec_long)
v4 <- via_read_table(vec_long)
v5 <- via_fct_relabel(vec_long)

all(sapply(list(v1, v2, v3, v4), FUN = identical, v5)) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850654/6105259
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: `vec_long = factor(vec_long) ; levels(vec_long) <- c("all", "cat", "dog")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a factor, which will also need some time, it could look like:

```
vec_fac <- as.factor(vec_long)
sapply(strsplit(levels(vec_fac), "_", TRUE), `[`, 2)[vec_fac]
```

In case the data should also be recoded:

```
levels(vec_fac) <- sapply(strsplit(levels(vec_fac), "_", TRUE), `[`, 2)
vec_fac
```

Benchmark:

```
bench::mark(
         Question = sapply(strsplit(vec_long, "_",  TRUE), `[`, 2)
       , HaveFactor = sapply(strsplit(levels(vec_fac), "_", TRUE), `[`, 2)[vec_fac]
       , CreateFactor = {vec_fac <- as.factor(vec_long)
         sapply(strsplit(levels(vec_fac), "_", TRUE), `[`, 2)[vec_fac]}
       )
#  expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 Question       16.2ms   16.4ms      59.6    1.17MB     51.7    15    13
#2 HaveFactor    233.9µs    251µs    3757.   234.42KB     16.8  1788     8
#3 CreateFactor  882.8µs  920.2µs    1073.   959.36KB     19.2   503     9
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't follow the distinction between your first scenario ("If you create a factor") and the second ("In case the data should also be recoded"). What do you mean by "in case the data should be recorded"?

Comment: In the first you just get the values and keep the data as it is. In the second you overwrite the data to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `read.table` like below

```
read.table(text = vec, sep = "_", header = FALSE)$V2
```

which gives

```
> read.table(text = vec, sep = "_", header = FALSE)$V2
 [1] "dog"       "alligator" "cat"       "cat"       "alligator" "alligator"
 [7] "cat"       "cat"       "cat"       "dog"       "dog"       "cat"
[13] "alligator" "alligator" "alligator" "cat"       "dog"       "alligator"
[19] "alligator" "cat"       "dog"       "cat"       "cat"       "dog"
[25] "dog"       "dog"       "dog"       "dog"       "alligator" "alligator"
```

Comment: This is clever but it's too specific to pattern of the data in this example. How could we use this method if we wanted to apply a different string processing?

Comment: @Emman The separator used in `strsplit` can be applied as an argument of `sep = ` in `read.table`

Comment: Yes, but in a different scenario, the type of processing could be -- for example -- removing digits from alphanumeric values: `stringr::str_replace_all(c("44dog123", "lion896", "1zebra5"), "[:digit:]", "")` which returns `[1] "dog"   "lion"  "zebra"`. Can we adapt `read.table()` for such string processing?

Comment: @Emman In that case, you can try `gsub("\\d+","",vec)`

Comment: For completeness, what you mean is: `vec <- c("44dog123", "lion896", "1zebra5"); read.table(text = gsub("\\d+", "", vec), header = FALSE)$V1`, which indeed returns `[1] "dog"   "lion"  "zebra"`. Indeed creative!

Comment: I've updated the post and added your method to the benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

I've also toyed with the idea of having a function that allows recoding of factors with regex. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800944/4241780.

In short

```
remotes::install_github("jwilliman/xfactor")

as.character(
    xfactor::xfactor(vec_very_long, levels = c(dog = "dog", cat = "cat", alligator = "alligator"))
)
```

The bits in quotes are the regex expressions, and the names the levels to replace them with.

This takes just under twice as long as the quickest answer above, but has greater flexibility in allowing for different regex patterns to be applied for each resulting factor level. Ie. good for cleaning messy data.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't completely understand. How would I pass a string processing function (e.g., `sapply(str_split(.x, "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2)`) to `xfactor()`?

Comment: @Emman You wouldn't. You have a define a new regex expression for each output level to be produced, ie. in the example you need a new regex for each animal. `xfactor` isn't suited to well defined data that follows a set pattern throughout. However, it *is* suited to recoding of character data that is messy and cannot be recoded with a single processing function, eg. hand entered data with typos and inconsistent formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that one way to solve this is with `forcats::fct_relabel()`.

```r
library(forcats)
library(stringr)

via_fct_relabel <- function(x) {
  x_factor <- as.factor(x)
  x_factor <- fct_relabel(x_factor, ~sapply(str_split(.x, "_",  n = 3), `[`, 2))
  as.character(x_factor)
}


vec_long <- sample(rep(c("animal_dog_xyz", "animal_cat_abc", "animal_alligator_tyl"), 10000))

result <- via_fct_relabel(vec_long)
head(result, n = 20)
#>  [1] "cat"       "dog"       "dog"       "cat"       "cat"       "alligator"
#>  [7] "cat"       "alligator" "alligator" "cat"       "alligator" "dog"      
#> [13] "cat"       "alligator" "dog"       "cat"       "cat"       "dog"      
#> [19] "cat"       "dog"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>